# Old IBM Thinkpad T42

Tags: thinkpad

I have an old IBM Thinkpad T42 from college that alive been using lately to hook up to my car and diagnose issues. The last few times I've tried to use it, occasionally the screen would be very dark and very hard to read. Sunlight helped make it more visible. Yesterday when I turned it on to use it, the screen was difficult to see and the system wouldn't boot. Shortly after initial startup I get two short beeps and it goes to the BIOS settings and shows me what's in the system.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See [this post](https://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?t=113546).  It is the exact same problem.  Did you google this problem before posting?

Comment: The first problem is the display. It might be easiest to get a complete Lid on eBay for your machine (returnable if DOA). I replaced a Lid this way on my T41 (now long gone). The second problem appears to be a hard drive failure (unrelated to display) and why you just get to BIOS. Make sure the machine is worth repairing.

Comment: I did do a quick Google search and saw that on laptops the two beeps means a board issue but it also said an error should display on screen.